# ¿Cómo se insertan varios registros según un radiobutton Si/No?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Bien pues de nuevo yo por acá, está vez quisiera saber como puedo insertar varios registros en una tabla "X", por ejemplo:
Pregunta 1 Si/NO

```
//Si responde si, ejecute un insert into (....)
//Si responde no, pues no haga nada.
```

son mas de 30 preguntas en total, código parcial que he intentado:

Nota: Si=1 / No=0

```
 if (this.radSiNo1ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Form_PQR_ComiteConvivenciaDatos" +
                    "(pqr_comPqr_Id,    pqr_comQ4_Codigo,   pqr_comQ4_Valor,    pqr_comQ4_FC,   pqr_comQ4_FM)" +
                    "VALUES" +
                    "(@pqr_comPqr_Id,   @pqr_comQ4_Codigo,  @pqr_comQ4_Valor,   getdate(),      getdate())", form_insert);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var lastIdenty = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comPqr_Id", lastIdenty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comQ4_Codigo", "41");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comQ4_Valor", "1");
            }
            else if (this.radSiNo2ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Form_PQR_ComiteConvivenciaDatos" +
                    "(pqr_comPqr_Id,    pqr_comQ4_Codigo,   pqr_comQ4_Valor,    pqr_comQ4_FC,   pqr_comQ4_FM)" +
                    "VALUES" +
                    "(@pqr_comPqr_Id,   @pqr_comQ4_Codigo,  @pqr_comQ4_Valor,   getdate(),      getdate())", form_insert);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var lastIdenty = cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comPqr_Id", lastIdenty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comQ4_Codigo", "42");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comQ4_Valor", "1");
            }
            else if (this.radSiNo3ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
            { (...)}
            else if (this.radSiNo4ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
            { (...)}
            else if (this.radSiNo5ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
            { (...)}
            else if (this.radSiNo6ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
            { (...)}
            else if (this.radSiNo7ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
            { (...)}
            else
            {
                //NO HACER NADA
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

.aspx

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radSiNo3ComitePQR" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ComitePQR" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">SI &nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">NO &nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: no entiendo.. cual es la pregunta???

Comment: Pues, de esa manera se insertan multiples registros?, porque no me funciona, no inserta nada de nada.

Comment: no es checked la propiedad que estas buscando?

Comment: y en teoria si son radio buttons.. es pq tenes multiples opciones y podes seleccionar una.. me parece que usaste el control equivocado.. no querias checkbox?? pq una ves que seleccionas un radio.. no se deselecciona a menos que esten en un group ...

Comment: Agregue captura del .aspx, estoy usando `<asp:RadioButtonList>`

Comment: Pero ahi tenes 2 radio por pregunta. Pon una parte del aspx de una pregunta para ver como defines los radio.

Comment: Pero ahi tenes 2 radio por pregunta. Pon una parte del aspx de una pregunta para ver como defines los radio.

Comment: Listo, compa agregados, veo que la primer parte del insert que es a otra tabla aparte estaa funcionando, pero estos inserts no funcionan, no insertan nada, los demas de inicio si, creería que tal vez no está tomando el @@Scope ? que opinas?

Comment: Eh.. estas ejecutando el query.. antes de pasar los parametro!!!! Ese es el problema..

Comment: Nope, en la otra que si inserta, estan iguales los parametros despues del query, aun así por si acaso lo pasé antes del query, mismo resultado. 0 registros en la tabla `Form_PQR_ComiteConvivenciaDatos`

Comment: quita los ELSE a todas tus preguntas, para que las condiciones en true inserten datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Vulpex,

Tienes varios problemas en éste código.

El primer problema que se puede ver es que estás ejecutando la consulta antes de asignar los parámetros (`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`).

El segundo problema que tienes aquí es que estas ejecutando un `SqlCommand` que no es el que le estas asignando la consulta `SQL`, estás creando un `SqlCommand` llamado `cmd2` pero no lo estás ejecutando en ningún momento, en cambio, ejecutas el `SqlCommand` llamado `cmd`, el cual no sabemos que es lo que contiene.

El tercer problema es un problema de lógica, ya que estás agrupando todos los `radioButton` diferentes en una cadena de `if/else`, lo cual sólo te va a insertar un dato en la base de datos, y los otros los va a omitir, porque ya ha cumplido una condición y va a salir de la cadena.

Deberías usar un `if` por cada `radioButton` que tengas en la página, te debería quedar algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
if (this.radSiNo1ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
{
     SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Form_PQR_ComiteConvivenciaDatos" +
         "(pqr_comPqr_Id,    pqr_comQ4_Codigo,   pqr_comQ4_Valor,    pqr_comQ4_FC,   pqr_comQ4_FM)" +
         "VALUES" +
         "(@pqr_comPqr_Id,   @pqr_comQ4_Codigo,  @pqr_comQ4_Valor,   getdate(),      getdate())", form_insert);

     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
     var lastIdenty = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

     cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comPqr_Id", lastIdenty);
     cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comQ4_Codigo", "41");
     cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comQ4_Valor", "1");
     cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

if (this.radSiNo2ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
{
     SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Form_PQR_ComiteConvivenciaDatos" +
          "(pqr_comPqr_Id,    pqr_comQ4_Codigo,   pqr_comQ4_Valor,    pqr_comQ4_FC,   pqr_comQ4_FM)" +
          "VALUES" +
          "(@pqr_comPqr_Id,   @pqr_comQ4_Codigo,  @pqr_comQ4_Valor,   getdate(),      getdate())", form_insert);

     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
     var lastIdenty = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

     cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comPqr_Id", lastIdenty);
     cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comQ4_Codigo", "42");
     cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pqr_comQ4_Valor", "1");
     cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }

 if (this.radSiNo3ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
 { (...)}

 if (this.radSiNo4ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
 { (...)}

 if (this.radSiNo5ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
 { (...)}

 if (this.radSiNo6ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
 { (...)}

 if (this.radSiNo7ComitePQR.SelectedValue == "1")
 { (...)}
```

Comment: Tenía esta sección abandonada mientras me daba paciencia para volver a revisar este tema, lo hice como me indicas con solo 3 radioButton y funcionó a la perfección! sólo resta replicarlo para todos los demás radioButtons. muchas gracias compa!